Random variable obtained from discrete and continuous Random variables
A random variable $Z$ is obtained as follows:
Given X $\sim U(0, 1)$ and $Y|(X=x) \sim Bern(x)$. If $Y = 1,
Z = X$. Otherwise, the experiment is repeated until $(X, Y)$ with $Y = 1$ is obtained. It is asked to find the pdf of $Z$.
My attempt:
$F_z(x) = P(Z\leq x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(Z\leq x,N=i)$
where $N =$ number of times experiment is done.
Let $u\leq x, P(X = u) = 1.du \qquad ...(1)$
$\implies P(X=u, Y=1) = u.du \qquad ...(2)$
$\implies P(Z\leq x,N=1) = \int_0^xu.du =\frac{x^2}{2}$
$P(X=u, Y=0) = (1-u).du$
$\implies P($experiment has to be repeated$) = \int_0^1(1-u).du =\frac{1}{2}$
$\implies P(Z\leq x, N=i) = (\frac{1}{2})^{i-1} (\frac{x^2}{2})$
I try to avoid the method of solving I used here in equation (1) and (2) where continuous variables have been treated like discrete for purpose of summation using integration. Strictly speaking, $P(X = u) = 0$ since X is a continuous variable. Would it be correct to use $P(X = u)  = du$ as in eqn (1) and (2)? And is there any other way to check the answer obtained for pdf of $Z$?

$\mathsf P(X=u)=0$, but $f_X(x)= \mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq 1}$ so use that...

The hierarchical model is
$$X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1) \\
Y \mid X \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(X) \\$$
and $Z = (X \mid Y = 1)$.  So it is natural to first compute the distribution of $X \mid Y$.  We have $$f_X(x) = 1, \quad 0 < x < 1,$$ and
$$\Pr[Y = y \mid X = x] = x^y (1-x)^{1-y}, \quad y \in \{0, 1\}.$$  And by Bayes' rule,
$$f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y) = \frac{\Pr[Y = y \mid X = x]f_X(x)}{\Pr[Y = y]}.$$  The only piece missing is the marginal probability $\Pr[Y = y]$.  We obtain this via the law of total probability:
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[Y = y] 
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \Pr[Y = y \mid X = x]f_X(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 x^y (1-x)^{1-y} \, dx \\
&= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}, & y = 0 \\ \frac{1}{2}, & y = 1 \end{cases} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}, \quad y \in \{0,1\}.
\end{align}$$
Therefore,
$$f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y) = 2x^y(1-x)^{1-y}, \quad 0 < x < 1, \quad y \in \{0, 1\}$$
and $$f_Z(z) = f_{X \mid Y}(z \mid 1) = 2z, \quad 0 < z < 1.$$

We calculated the integral by simply considering the two cases $y = 0$ and $y = 1$ separately.  That the result is $Y \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(1/2)$, is to be expected, since the distribution of $X$ is symmetric.  Also, we did not need to calculate $\Pr[Y = 0]$; we just get it for free because $Y$ can only be Bernoulli, given that its support is on $\{0,1\}$.
In Bayesian statistics, we can recognize this question as a special case of the binomial likelihood with beta conjugate prior.  The prior is $X \sim \operatorname{Beta}(a = 1, b = 1)$ which is the same as the uniform distribution.  The likelihood for a single observation is $Y \mid X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 1, p = X)$, which of course is Bernoulli when $n = 1$.  Then the posterior for $X$ is beta distributed, namely
$$X \mid Y \sim \operatorname{Beta}(a + Y, 1 + b - Y) = \operatorname{Beta}(1+Y, 2-Y),$$
and when $Y = 1$, we have
$$Z = (X \mid Y = 1) \sim \operatorname{Beta}(2,1)$$
which has density
$$f_Z(z) = \frac{\Gamma(2+1)}{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(1)} z^{2-1} (1-z)^{1-1} = 2z, \quad 0 < z < 1.$$

Thanks. This was the conventional solution I was hoping for,  compared to my messier approach. However, is there any fault in my solution, especially equation (1) and (2).

@SK25 Your approach isn't wrong, but it isn't really a standard way to express the desired probabilities and plays "fast and loose" with notation, especially the use of $du$ to describe probabilities that should be better expressed as densities.  If you were to continue, you would find $$F_Z(x) = \Pr[Z \le x] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-(i-1)} \frac{x^2}{2} = x^2,$$ hence $f_Z(x) = F'_Z(x) = 2x$.  So you do get the correct result, but most mathematicians and statisticians would need to take extra time to parse your work.

You are looking for the pdf for $Z$ , not its CDF.
You have the pdf for $X$, and the conditional pmf for $Y$ given $X$; since you know their distributions.
$\begin{align}f_X(x) &= \mathbf 1_{0\leq x\leq 1}\\[2ex]\mathsf P(Y=y\mid X=x) &= x^y(1-x)^{(1-y)}\,\mathbf 1_{y\in\{0,1\}}\end{align}$
So just use them.
You've already done most of the work, so here you go...
$\qquad\begin{align}f_{Z}(z) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_X(z)\,\mathsf P(N=n\mid Z=z) \\[1ex] &= f_X(z)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf P(Y=1\mid X=z)\, \mathsf P(Y=0)^{(n-1)}\\[1ex] &= f_X(z)\,\mathsf P(Y=1\mid X=z)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\int_0^1 f_X(x)\,\mathsf P(Y=0\mid X=x)\,\mathrm d x\right)^{(n-1)}\\[1ex] &= \mathbf 1_{0\leq z\leq 1}\cdot z\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\int_0^1 (1-x)\,\mathrm dx\right)^{n-1} \\[1ex] &=  z~\mathbf 1_{0\leq z\leq 1}~\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^{n-1}}\\[4ex]\therefore\quad f_Z(z) &= 2z\,\mathbf 1_{0\leq z\leq 1} \end{align}$

If you still wish for the CDF, then of course ...
$\qquad\begin{align}F_Z(z) &= \int_0^z f_Z(s)\,\mathrm d s\end{align}$

$(X_n,Y_n)$ $n=1,2,\ldots $ are iid. If $T=\inf\{n; Y_n=1\}$ we are asked for $\Pr(X_T<z).$
$$\Pr(X_T<z, T=n|X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1},Y_1,\ldots,Y_{n-1})=\Pr(X_n<z \cap \{Y_n=1\})(1-X_1)\ldots (1-X_{n-1})==E(\Pr(X_n<z \cap \{Y_n=1\}|X_n))(1-X_1)\ldots (1-X_{n-1})$$ We use $$E(\Pr(X_n<z \cap \{Y_n=1\}|X_n))=E(X_n1_{X_n<z})=\int_0^zxdx=\frac{z^2}{2}$$  getting
$\Pr(X_T<z, T=n)$
$$=E(\Pr(X_T<z, T=n|X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1},Y_1,\ldots,Y_{n-1}))=\frac{z^2}{2^n}$$ and $\Pr(X_T<z)=z^2.$

$Z$ has the same support as $X$.  It is not a discrete random variable.
